# Program Not Recognizing Where Characters Are In An Array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I'm trying to write a program where a character moves through a 2D array, and there are certain obstacles in the way that it will interact with. The maze looks like this (though the placement of the obstacles changes each time it's ran):

```
x       |               \   
        /       /           \
                \           
    /       /           \   
\       \       |       |
```

The x represents the player, and every second, it moves one space further to the right. If it comes into contact with a "/", it moves one space to the right and one space down. If it comes into contact with a "\", it moves one space to the right and one space up. And if it comes into contact with a "|", it automatically dies. However, the program doesn't seem to recognize when there is an obstacle in the player's path. It just moves straight the whole time, and looks like this at the end:

```
x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
        /       /           \
                \           
    /       /           \   
\       \       |       |
```

Here is my code that should check if there is an obstacle:

```
        if (maze[l][f].equals("/")) {
            if ((l-1) < 0) {
                System.out.println("You died on column " + (f + 1));
                System.exit(0);
                y+=1;
            } else {
                l-=1;
                f+=1;
                maze[l][f] = "x";
                y+=1;
            }
        } else if (maze[l][f].equals("\\")) {
            if ((l+1) >= rows){
                System.out.println("You died on column " + (f + 1));
                System.exit(0);
                y+=1;
            } else {
                l+=1;
                f+=1;
                maze[l][f] = "x";
                y+=1;
            }
        } else if (maze[l][f].equals("|")) {
            System.out.println("You died on column" + (f+1));
            System.exit(0);
            y+=1;
        } else {
            f+=1;
            maze[l][f] = "x";
            y+=1;
        }
```

And here is the code that creates the maze:

```
private static int rows;
private static int columns;
public static String[][] maze = new String[5][8];
public String[][] grid() {  
    Random rand = new Random();
    int prob;
    String obstacle = "";
    boolean enabled = true;
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            if (enabled == true) {
                prob = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
                if (prob == 1) {obstacle = "|"; enabled = false;}
                else if (prob == 2 || prob == 3) {obstacle = "/"; enabled = false;}
                else if (prob == 4 || prob == 5) {obstacle = "\\"; enabled = false;}
                else {obstacle = ""; enabled = true;}
            }
            else {enabled = true; obstacle = "";}
            maze[r][c] = obstacle;
        }
    }
    return maze;
}
```

I don't see what's wrong with it. If you have any ideas, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming `l` is the current line, it should be `l+=1`when char is `/`, not `l-=1`. As starting row is row 0, you add 1 to go down, and substract to go up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets says you are currently on position [0,0], with the grid you wrote in the question:
You got `l=0; f=0`
The position is a space char, code is executed and reach the last `else`part.

Now, what happens? `f` is incremented, that means you move to the right and now stand on [0,1]. And then you mark your position by writing an `x` on this new position.

On the next execution, the character is not a space character as you expect but an `x`. You reach the else block again and move once more on the right to [0,2]. Again, you mark your new position with a `x`, overwriting the `|` that was standing there. And so on...

What you should do: mark your position only if the character is not a special char and before movign to the next position

```
    if (maze[l][f].equals("/")) {
        if ((l+1) >= rows) {
            System.out.println("You died on column " + (f + 1));
            System.exit(0);
            y+=1;
        } else {
            //maze[l][f] = "x"; // only if you want to replace the '/' char
            l+=1; // to go down, add one (first line has index 0)
            f+=1;
            y+=1;
        }
    } else if (maze[l][f].equals("\\")) {
        if ((l-1) < 0){
            System.out.println("You died on column " + (f + 1));
            System.exit(0);
            y+=1;
        } else {
            maze[l][f] = "x"; // only if you want to replace the '\' char
            l-=1; // to go up, substractone (first line has index 0)
            f+=1;
            y+=1;
        }
    } else if (maze[l][f].equals("|")) {
        System.out.println("You died on column" + (f+1));
        System.exit(0);
        y+=1;
    } else {
        maze[l][f] = "x"; // mark the current position before moving to the next one
        f+=1;
        y+=1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dude you're the GOAT

Answer (score 0):

you change the current position into "x" after you change the l and f variables.

so the current position always turns out to be "x" and the character keeps moving to the right.